# While loading data, Access gets close to the 2GB limit

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Every month, I do some analysis on a customer database. My predecessor would create a segment in Eloqua (Our CRM) for each country, and then spend about 10 (tedious, slow) hours refreshing them all. When I took over, I knew that I wouldn't be able to do it in Excel (we had over 10 million customers) so I used Access.

This process has worked pretty well. We're now up to 12 million records, and it's still going strong. However, when importing the master list of customers prior to doing any work on it, the database is inflating. This month it hit 1.3 GB.

Now, I'm not importing ALL of my columns - only 3. And Access freezes if I try to do my manipulations on a linked table. What can I do to reduce the size of my database during import? My source files are linked CSVs with only the bare minimum of columns; after I import the data, my next steps have to be:

- Manipulate the data to get counts instead of individual lines
- Store the manipulated data (only a few hundred KB)
- Empty my imported table
- Compress and Repair

This wouldn't be a problem, but i have to do all of this 8 times (8 segments, each showing a different portion of the database), and the 2GB limit is looming over the next horizon.

An alternate question might be: How can I simulate / re-create the "Linked Table" functionality in MySQL/MariaDB/something else free?

Comment: How big is the database after compression?

Comment: You could split your data into different access databases, then union any where you need data from more than one at a time. Of course this has it's drawbacks and any use of Access as backend may eventually lead to this type of thing. Many better choices for backend out there.

Comment: I can suggest 2 workarounds - One is to delete the prior imported table & compact before doing the new import.  That may buy you enough space.  Second is to use a vba script to process the input one line at a time and just import the columns you need.  I have an app set up like this that I can share if you want more information.  (I had to do it that way because my input file was over 2G and I couldn't import or attach it any other way.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such big number of records MS Access with 2 GB limit is not good solution as data storage. I would use MySQL as backend:

- Create table in MySQL and link it to MS Access
- Import CSV data directly to MySQL table using native import features of MySQL. Of course Access can be used for data import, but it will work slower.
- Use Access for data analyse using this linked MySQL table as regular table.

Comment: I second this idea!

Answer (score 1):

You could import the CSV to a (new/empty) separate Access database file.

Then, in your current application, link the table from that file. Access will not freeze during your operations as it will when linking text files directly.